# Cloudformation stack default parameter SSM Parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I am trying to launch a jupyterlab instance using cloudformation (its something I do a lot and sagemaker does not have a 1y free tier) so the beginning looks like this which does not work. Specifically the password parameter

```
# AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Creates a Jupyter Lab Instance with an Elastic Load Balancer


Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: >-
      Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
    Default: eduinstance
  VPC:
    Description: VPC ID of the VPC in which to deploy this stack.
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    ConstraintDescription: Must be the name of a valid VPC
    Default: vpc-10a7ac6a
  Subnets:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Default: subnet-8cde25d3,subnet-531fda72,subnet-4bbe3006
    Description: >-
      Subnets for the Elastic Load Balancer.
      Please include at least two subnets
  Password: 
    Type: String
    NoEcho: false
    MinLength: 4
    Default: '{{resolve:ssm:JLabPassword:1}}'
    Description: Password to set for Jupyter Lab
  EBSVolumeSize:
    Type: Number
    Description: EBS Volume Size (in GiB) for the instance
    Default: 8
    MinValue: 8
    MaxValue: 64000
    ConstraintDescription: Please enter a value between 8 GB and 64 TB
  EC2InstanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.micro
      - c5.large
      - m5.large
    Description: Enter t2.micro, c5.large or m5.large. Default is t2.micro.


Conditions:
  JupyterPasswordDefault: !Equals
    - !Ref Password
    - DEFAULT

Resources:
  ALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties: 
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups: 
        - !GetAtt [ALBSG, GroupId]
      Subnets: !Ref Subnets
      Type: application
  
  ALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions: 
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ALB
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
  
  ALBTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Port: 8888
      Protocol: HTTP
      Targets: 
        - Id: !Ref ComputeInstance
      TargetType: instance
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  
  ComputeInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref ComputeIAMRole

  
  ComputeInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: !Select [0, !Ref Subnets]
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: '{{resolve:ssm:/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2:33}}'
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !GetAtt [ComputeSG, GroupId]
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ComputeInstanceProfile
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            VolumeType: gp2
            VolumeSize: !Ref EBSVolumeSize
            DeleteOnTermination: true
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub
          - |
            #!/bin/bash
            yum update -y
            yum install python3-pip -y
            yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y
            cd /home/ec2-user/
            wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
            sudo -u ec2-user bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/anaconda
            echo "PATH=/home/ec2-user/anaconda/bin:$PATH" >> /etc/environment
            source /etc/environment
            jupyter notebook --generate-config
            mkdir .jupyter
            cp /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py /home/ec2-user/.jupyter/
            echo "c = get_config()" >> .jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
            echo "c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'" >> .jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
            NB_PASSWORD=$(python3 -c "from notebook.auth import passwd; print(passwd('${password}'))")
            echo "c.NotebookApp.password = u'$NB_PASSWORD'" >> .jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
            rm Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
            mkdir Notebooks
            chmod 777 -R Notebooks .jupyter
            su -c "jupyter lab" -s /bin/sh ec2-user
          - password: !Ref Password #!If [JupyterPasswordDefault, '{{resolve:ssm:JupyterLabPassword:1}}', !Ref Password]

  
  ALBSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: Security Group for JupyterLab ALB. Created Automatically.
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: Allows HTTP Traffic from anywhere
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          IpProtocol: tcp

  ComputeSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: Security Group for JupyterLab EC2 Instance. Created Automatically.
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - Description: Allows JupyterLab Server Traffic from ALB.
          FromPort: 8888
          IpProtocol: tcp
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt [ALBSG, GroupId]
          ToPort: 8890
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: Allows SSH Access from Anywhere
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          IpProtocol: tcp
  
  ComputeIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
              - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Description: Allows EC2 Access to S3. Created Automatically.
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess

Outputs:
  URL:
    Description: URL of the ALB
    Value: !Join 
      - ''
      - - 'http://'
        - !GetAtt 
          - ALB
          - DNSName
  
  ConnectionString:
    Description: Connection String For SSH On EC2
    Value: !Join
      - ''
      - - 'ssh -i "'
        - !Ref KeyName
        - '.pem" ec2-user@'
        - !GetAtt
          - ComputeInstance
          - PublicDnsName
```

It however interprets the string literally so I don't actually get my password but the resolve... itself.

[image: Screenshot of the Actual Parameter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments and new, updated template by OP, and to expand on @DennisTraub answer.

[SSM parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) resolve in almost all cases in the template, with the exception of `UserData` (btw, `Init` will also not work). This means, that dynamic reference will **not resolve** when used in the context of `UserData`. This is due to security issues.

`UserData` can be read in **plain text** by anyone who can view basic attributes of the instance. This means, that your `JLabPassword` would be in plain text available in `UserData` for everyone to see, if such resolution would be possible.

To rectify the issue, the SSM parameters should be used in `UserData` as follows:

1. Attach IAM permission `ssm:GetParameter` to the instance role/profile which allows instance to access the SSM Parameter Store.
2. Instead on `{{resolve:ssm:JLabPassword:1}}` in your Parameter, you can just pass `JLabPassword` so that the name of the SSM paramtter gets passed into the `UserData`, not the actual value of it.
3. In the `UserData`, please use AWS CLI [get-parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameter.html) to get the actual value of your `JLabPassword`.

The above ensures that the value of `JLabPassword` is kept private and not visible in plain text in `UserData`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be the issue. The way I solved it was firstly set the parameter name as the default password (JLabPassword). Then I used a conditional to check if the password is equal to the default password. If it was I used the following command to get the password: $(aws ssm get-parameter --name ${PasswordParameter} --region ${AWS::Region} --output text | awk '{print $(NF-1)}') and substituted the parameter and region through the template. After that I added the IAM Policy to Allow ssm:GetParameter on resource '*" and attached it to the instance's IAM Role.

Comment: @KaizadWadia No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Great team work!

Answer (score 1):

Your passwort parameter's default value is missing the service name (`ssm`) as well as single quotes.

```
// What you have:
Password:
  Default: {{resolve:JupyterPassword:1}}
  ...

// What it should be:
Password:
  Default: '{{resolve:ssm:JupyterPassword:1}}'
  ...
```

*Update:* You've fixed the code in your question. Did my answer and the comments below solve your question? If not, I'm not sure what else you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for answering. TBH that wasn't really my code I changed it to make it work but when its actually Default: {{resolve:ssm:JupyterLabPassword:1}} what I get in cloudformation with a red alert: Template format error: [/Parameters/Password/Default] map keys must be strings; received a map instead

Comment: @KaizadWadia It should be `Default: '{{resolve:ssm:JupyterPassword:1}}'` - single quotes should be there.

Comment: The problem was that it was not written in quotes but just curly braces... Another parameter I have (that works) also does this... The problem is that when put in quotes the whole thing is just taken literally and I still don't get my parameter :(. @Marcin

Comment: @KaizadWadia I assure you that it works as intendet. Please update your question with **exactly** code you are using.

Comment: @Marcin I updated the question to include my new problem although you were right in saying it should be in quotes.

Comment: @KaizadWadia Your `Password` is correct now. It will be resolved inside the template, but parameter value will still show it as a literal string for security reasons.

Comment: @Marcin No its not... I just deployed it and when I put in pass1234 it doesn't work but {{resolve:ssm:JLabPassword:0}} and it does...

Comment: If you don't believe me I just pasted my entire code you can try to deploy it yourself.

Comment: P.S. What security reasons could there be? As far as SSM is concerned its just some random string its not encrypted or anything just plaintext.

Comment: @KaizadWadia Your template shows that you are using incorrect paramter: `'{{resolve:ssm:JLabPassword:0}}'`. There is no version 0 on your screenshot.

Comment: @Marcin huh, that should have been a 1. It still does not resolve though. Very strange considering the EC2 instance AMI loads fine.

Comment: @KaizadWadia Let me make an answer, now I see the full template. Could provide it earlier if you've included the template from the start.

Comment: Okay, thanks again for your help. I apologize for not including the template from the start. I thought this would be a minor syntax issue with a quick fix. @Marcin